# Array of path-name strings to treeview

Tags: javascript, treeview

I have input data like:

```
['Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4a',
'Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4b',
'Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4c',
'Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4a',
'Level 1c/Level 2d/Level 3b/ Level4d',
'Level 1c/Level 2d/Level 3b/ Level4e',
'Level 1c/Level 2d/Level 3b/ Level4f']
```

Now I would like to convert it to treeview array like this:

```
tree: [
                {
                    name: 'Level 1',
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'Level 2',
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: 'Level 3',
                                    children: [
                                        {name: 'Level 4a'},
                                        {name: 'Level 4b'},
                                        {name: 'Level 4c'}
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Level 1c',
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'Level 2d',
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: 'Level 3b',
                                    children: [
                                        {name: 'Level 4d'},
                                        {name: 'Level 4e'},
                                        {name: 'Level 4f'}
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

There is a way to iterate, but its to much complex, I guess. 
What is the best optimal way to do this?

Comment: please add what you have tried. is the data sorted?

Comment: btw, the given data does not match the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes data is sorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an array of the last inserted objects and check if the name is not equal to the last one. if so, add a new object.

```js
var data = ['Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/Level4a', 'Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/Level4b', 'Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/Level4c', 'Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/Level4a', 'Level 1c/Level 2d/Level 3b/Level4d', 'Level 1c/Level 2d/Level 3b/Level4e', 'Level 1c/Level 2d/Level 3b/Level4f'],
    tree = [],
    levels = [{ children: tree }];

data.forEach(s => s.split('/').forEach((name, i) => {
    if (!levels[i + 1] || levels[i + 1].name !== name) {
        levels[i].children = levels[i].children || [];
        levels[i].children.push(levels[i + 1] = { name });
    }
}));

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This will not work well if data array is mixed and for instance last data element will start with 'Level 1' again.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk, the data is sorted, as op has stated.

Comment: Oh yes, I apologize. Your solution will work in the case when data is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 `reduce`s. The first one is to loop thru the array. The second `reduce` is to loop thru the `split()` string. Use `find()` to check an element exist on an array

```js
var arr = ['Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4a', 'Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4b', 'Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4c', 'Level 1/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4a', 'Level 1c/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4d', 'Level 1c/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4e', 'Level 1c/Level 2/Level 3/ Level4f'];

var result = arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  v.split('/').reduce((a, o, i) => {
    if (i === 0) var p = a;
    else var p = a.children = a.children || [];

    let f = p.find(x => x.name === o.trim());
    if (!f) {
      f = {name: o.trim()};
      p.push(f);
    }

    return f;
  }, c);

  return c;
}, []);


console.log(result);
```